# unable to get resources path

Tags: javascript, ios4, uiwebview

I have added searchView.js by dragging and dropping into the Resources folder.  I selected the "Copy items into destination group's folder(if needed)".

Still, I get path as nil during compilation, what should I do?

Code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"searchWebView" ofType:@"js"];
NSString *jsCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCode];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is named `searchView.js` then your code should probably be:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"searchView" ofType:@"js"];
NSString *jsCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCode];
```

Comment: Sorry for typing error but my file's name is "searchWebView.js" only.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response but i got the answer. I was missing it to add into resources. http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/01/12/search-and-highlight-text-in-uiwebview/comment-page-4/#comment-13794. :)